# Отличается ли const, let и var в плане производительности и памяти в js?

Tags: javascript

Изучаю js, и назрел вопрос отличается ли const от var и let в плане производительности и памяти которую занимают переменные?
Вопрос может показаться глупым, но информации по нему я не нашел.

Comment: [Is there a performance difference between 'let' and 'var' in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21467642/2881286)

Comment: В этой статье сказано, что var и let работают одинаково, если имеют одинаковую область видимости. То есть, если let не используется в блоке  внутри функции, имея более узкую область видимости.

Comment: @Leonid, ты как-то выборочно читаешь

Comment: After testing this in Chrome and Firefox, this shows that let is faster than var, but only when inside a different scope than the main scope of a function. In the main scope, var and let are roughly identical in performance. In IE11 and MS Edge, let and var are roughly equal in performance in both cases.

Comment: let is faster than var, but only when inside a different scope than the main scope of a function

Comment: let быстрее var только в том случае если они внутри, вложенного в основную функцию, блока (scope).

Comment: @Leonid, а еще там написано: _After Chrome v60, no further regressions have cropped up. var and let are neck and neck, with var only ever winning by less than 1%_

Comment: Там человек приложил тест, я его проиграл и получил результаты, описанные мною. А что там кто еще написал: какая разница? Чем-то это подтверждается? У меня не может быть Хрома старее, как понимаете...

Comment: Это вообще странный вопрос, почему Хром? EcmaScript просто язык, синтаксис, каждый его реализует по-своему. При чем здесь вообще браузер?

Comment: @Leonid, если _каждый его реализует по-своему_ - то вопрос производительности не имеет смысла, так как зависит именно от реализации

Comment: Да, но при прочих равных var будет иметь область видимости большую, чем let. При реализации языка новый язык не изобретают.

Comment: @Leonid. и как это может быть связано с производительностью?

Comment: Никак, но в вопросе была речь и про память.

Comment: @Leonid, а с памятью это как может быть связано?

Comment: ОНИ ДОЛЬШЕ СУЩЕСТВУЮТ В ПАМЯТИ

Comment: @Leonid, ты можешь это как-то подтвердить?

Comment: Подозреваю, что без изучения генерируемого байткода/машинного кода (jit) все эти разговоры ни о чём (но тогда нужен человек, который умеет копаться в js-движках)

Comment: я думаю, что @Leonid имел в виду, что `let` внутри какого-то цикла, после его выполнения, удалиться из памяти, в отличии от `var`, которая благодаря хостингу (всплытию) перемен будет в глобальной видимости  и лежать там до полного завершения выполнения всего кода

Comment: @Август, это все зависит от конкретной реализации

Answer (score 0):

На производительность и память, скорее, влияет контекст в которых переменные существуют, а также область их видимости. Однако, из-за поведения var как раз в плане области видимости, она будет потреблять **больше ресурсов на единицу времени**.

---

Всем, кто не может обойтись без родной `var`: ПОЛЬЗУЙТЕСЬ НА ЗДОРОВЬЕ. Она такая же как и let/const. Главное, чтобы эти переменные сидели в функциях, а не захламляли глобальное пространство. Об этом надо беспокоиться. В плане быстродействия все одинаковы. Но `var`, согласитесь, имеет побочные эффекты.
Вы, конечно, можете использовать `i1, i2, i3` в блоках одного уровня, но может не стоит?

```
console.log(i); // i в этот момент времени существует, но не инициализирована
//console.log(j);  j в этот момент времени не существует

if(1){
    var i = 10;
    let j = 10; // j вообще существует только в этот момент времени!!!!!!!
}

// i в этот момент времени существует. j - нет.
// i в этот момент времени существует. j - нет.
// i в этот момент времени существует. j - нет.
// i в этот момент времени существует. j - нет.
// i в этот момент времени существует. j - нет.
// i в этот момент времени существует. j - нет.
// i в этот момент времени существует. j - нет.
// i в этот момент времени существует. j - нет.
// i в этот момент времени существует. j - нет.
// i в этот момент времени существует. j - нет.

console.log(i); // i в этот момент времени существует
//console.log(j);  j в этот момент времени не существует
```

---

**Попробуй подождать, когда там удалится значение i!**

```js
if(1){
var i = 555555555555555555555555555555;
let j = 555555555555555555555555555555;
}

let select = document.getElementById('memorydetector');

select.onchange = function(){

if(this.value != '0') document.getElementById('result').textContent = window[this.value];
}
```

```css
#memorydetector {
padding: 4px;
}

#result {
 min-height: 20px;
 width: 300px;
 padding: 10px;
 font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<select id="memorydetector">
<option value="0">no var</option>
<option value="i">i</option>
<option value="j">j</option>
</select>

<div id="result">
  
</div>
```

Comment: почему _она будет потреблять больше ресурсов на единицу времени_?

Comment: Потому, что когда на ее месте let уже высвободит память, var продолжит свое существование. И, следовательно, будет занимать память.

Comment: Почему ты так думаешь?

Comment: А ты же знаешь, что твой пример упадет на второй строчке и дальше выполнение не пойдет, поэтому комментарии после этой строчки бессмысленны?

Comment: С "существует" у тебя неточность. Это зависит от реализации. Если переменная не используется - ее могут убрать, а если используется, то некорректно сравнивать, так как для доступа с let в этом месте нужна вторая переменная.

Comment: Вам же пишут: лучше напишите свой ответ, чем минусовать. Погляжу: боитесь ответы давать на общетеоретические и неконкретные вопросы. Должны понимать: этот сайт пополняется контнентом за счёт вопросов и ответов. Поисковиками индексируется мгновенно. Люди сюда переходят получить ответы, а не рассованные по щелям комменты или ссылки на материалы. Отвечайте как знаете, а не ссылками закидывайте.

Comment: Можно подкорректировать сам вопрос и корректно, развёрнуто ответить.

Comment: Кто пишет _лучше напишите свой ответ, чем минусовать_? :) Если ответ плохой - его надо минусовать.

Comment: Ну так ты ж ее автоматом положил в window :) не клади  - все будет ок :-)

Comment: Напиши с eval() чтобы доступ был не в window. Проверим.

Comment: Фишка в том, что ответы, которые исправляют ошибку в чьём-то коде, сайту контента не добавят. Мусор только, у кого такие коды и такие ошибки ещё возникнут - маловероятно. А вот на общетеоретические вопросы люди будут переходить и изучать. И ничего не увидят, в лучшем случае минус вопросу и ссылка куда-то. Пишите ответы, не стесняйтесь.

Comment: И логично и бесполезно одновременно. Кстати на заметку, пока идет цикл, будет работать сборщик мусора. Может так получиться, что вы получите кучу мусорных let на одну var в памяти. Но скорее всего они живут +- одинаково где- то в глубинах интерпретатора.

Comment: Бесполезно за ленивых балбесов код писать, гоняясь за баллами. На все подобные вопросы можно найти документацию и немного посидеть. А вот вопросы у людей где какой подход применить, технологию использовать - остаются без ответа.

Comment: Баллы мало на что влияют, поберегите свои нервы. Ну получили пару минусов, подумаешь. Другое дело что кодом вы тут ничего не докажите и надо лезть внутрь самого интерпретатора. Сам JS снаружи может скрыть от вас let, а на самом деле в тихую хранить эту ячейку памяти до выхода из scope и переиспользовать при необходимости. Вот я не могу точно сказать, а ковырять какой-нибудь node.js ради этого считаю непрактичным. То есть какая реальная польза от этого? Экономия байта? Проще алгоритм писать хороший

Comment: Да ведь я давно про другое. Просто делюсь тем, что мне, как новичку, режет глаза. С одной стороны сайт построен на однозначных ответах, а с другой - самого интересные вещи остаются без ответа. Вопрос можно минусануть и он уже токсичный: на него можно не отвечать.

Comment: Есть такое, тут сидят разные люди и у каждого из них разное видение на то, что они считают хорошим и плохим. Кому-то легче поставить минус без пояснений, а кто-то отпишет хороший ответ, потратив свое время. В любом случае нервы дороже, а время можно потратить не на споры, а на ответ ещё одного нуждающегося. И да, к минусам без пояснений в вопросах я уже привык и бороться с этим сложно.

Comment: _Вопрос можно минусануть и он уже токсичный_ обрати внимание, что данный вопрос никто не минусовал, поэтому не совсем понятно твое негодование :)

Comment: Надо у автора вопроса спросить получил ли он что хотел?) Зато я сниппеты научился вставлять. И слова выделять. Вообще, многое здесь за два дня вспомнил и узнал. Все замечательно, но ответите вы на вопрос или нет? Отличаются var, let и const?

Comment: @Leonid, так вроде ж выяснили, что нет, но может зависеть от реализации

Comment: Теперь выяснили, когда второй ответ появился, а так только слухи были.

Answer (score 0):

при всплытии (хостинге) переменных над `var`происходит немного больше процессов, а именно её инициализация - присвоение **значения** `undefined` а так же присвоение **типа** `undefined`, в то время как `let` и `const` остаются неинициализированными. в данном случае нагрузка идет на построение синтаксического дерева, но она вообще незначительная

Comment: Ну значит все было не зря.

Comment: Что значит _остаются неинициализированными_? Чем отличается нагрузка на построение синтаксического дерева?

Comment: @Grundy, неинициализированная значит, что переменная объявляется и под неё выделяется память, но ей не присваивается значение. вот здесь наглядный пример по ссылке https://miro.medium.com/max/726/1*pUqWuCzYCP79tOm4gGzXIw.png .

Comment: @Grundy, а нагрузка заключается в том, что при инициализации `var`, как уже писал выше, мы задаем значение и тип переменной по умолчанию, **затем снова их меняем, когда дело доходит до присвоения значения**. это двойная робота, чего нет у `let` и `const`

Comment: @Август, ссылка битая

Comment: @Grundy, просто выделите всю ссылку картинки, для удобства вот еще раз `https://miro.medium.com/max/726/1*pUqWuCzYCP79tOm4gGzXIw.png` в виде строки

Comment: Ты уверен, что это именно так работает во всех реализациях? Ты уверен, что есть разница между инициализацией undefined и неинициализацией?

Comment: _просто выделите всю ссылку картинки_ - наверное лишнее что-то захватывал, ошибка была. Для ссылок можно использовать следующий код: `[text](url)` тогда не будет биться

Comment: @Grundy, ну если на **ты**, то я не против) и за совет со ссылками низкий поклон. на счет *"Ты уверен, что это именно так работает во всех реализациях?"* - **да**, опираясь на общедоступную теорию. *"Ты уверен, что есть разница между инициализацией undefined и неинициализацией?"* - **нет**, но это вполне логично и логика так же основана на общедоступной теории. конечно же, если я не прав, то поправ**Ь** меня. для этого мы здесь и собрались. с Уважением

Comment: общедоступная теория она такая :) может и ошибаться. Фактически это все отдано на откуп реализации, то есть инициализация переменных может не отличаться до из использования и чтобы узнать точно, нужно смотреть конкретные движки