# Как работать с объектами и массивами в JavaScript? (rest, spread)

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты

```
const orderIds = [4, 2, 1, 3]

const people = [
    { id: 3, name: 'Tom'},
    { id: 2, name: 'Bill'},
    { id: 1, name: 'Jack'},
    { id: 4, name: 'Bob'}
]
// Bob Bill Jack Tom
```

Нужно вынести в консоль данные из объекта в порядке указанном в массиве.
То есть, поменять в объекте ключи id в том порядке, которые указан в массиве.

Comment: цикл по массиву и потом цикл по объекту. в чём трабл?

Comment: Задание неясное. (rest, spread)? Где-то сказано, что нужно использовать в решении эти операторы? Тогда почему нет этого в самом задании? Нужно вывести данные из объекта? Из какого объекта? Есть целый массив из объектов. В порядке, указанном в массиве? Этот порядок связан с id каждого объекта или с чем? Поменять ключи в объекте??? На что поменять, в каком объекте? Единственное осмысленное здесь ожидаемый вывод: `Bob Bill Jack Tom` - он действительно соответствует заданию?

Comment: Да, такие люди всегда найдутся. Всем всё всегда понятно, но будет такой буквоед, что спасения от него не будет. 
Это ведь не техническое задание в компании, никто за это денег не даст, никто не понесёт ответственности, это вообще по факту для всех присутствующих - ничто! 
Скажите, вы писали это в конце рабочего дня? После ссоры с менеджером проекта или собственником проекта? Вас отругали за неточное выполнение задания? Или вас регулярно забрасывают плохо поставленными ТЗ? 

К чему это было?! Более того, ДО вашего сообщения уже было дано несколько правильных ответов.

Comment: @Spawnet лично я поставил вопросу + и поставил ответам плюсы, именно для этого я и хотел, чтобы вопрос был корректно сформулирован. А так не совсем ясно: правильные ответы или нет. Я считаю, что у вас должна быть обратная связь. Поставил + вопросу потому, что есть очень интересные ответы и только поэтому. Кто-то поставил минус (а их 4) и просто пошел дальше. Отметил закрытие (тоже 4) и пошел дальше. А я пишу, и вы знаете что мне не нравится и можете сделать выводы. Что до вопроса, то можете для эксперимента убрать комментарий с ожидаемым выводом и узнать, сможет ли кто-то понять что надо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Без возможных потерь данных (если помимо `name` в объектах будут еще свойства):

```js
const orderIds = [4, 2, 1, 3];
const people = [
  { id: 3, name: 'Tom'},
  { id: 2, name: 'Bill'},
  { id: 1, name: 'Jack'},
  { id: 4, name: 'Bob'},
];

(
  ppl => console.log(...orderIds.map(id => ppl[id].name))  // 2. вывод данных, два прохода
)(
  Object.fromEntries(people.map(     // 1. преобразование из массива в объект, два прохода
    ({ id, ...rest }) => [id, { ...rest }]
  ))
);
```

Конструкции вида `Object.fromEntries(arr)` и `...arr.map()` содержат "скрытые" циклы - вместо них можно использовать `reduce` или процедурный цикл, в каждом таком случае получив один проход по данным вместо двух.
Таким образом, это примерно среднее по эффективности решение. Более скоростная комбинация редьюсов/форов и IIFE выглядела бы уж чересчур эзотерично :)

Кстати об IIFE, оно здесь только чтобы веселее было (это по сути делает хэштаблицу автоосвобождаемой, готовой к GC сразу после выполнения выражения) - так делать совсем не обязательно, под хранение ХТ можно и переменную ввести. Показываю только потому что на собеседованиях такие трюки иногда добавляют "звездочек".

А вложенные циклы (перепоиск/перефильтровка элементов на каждой итерации, как в принятом ответе) == зло: такие решения наименее производительны, плюс иногда приводят к гейзенбагам . Минздрав предупреждает.

Comment: _«на собеседованиях такие трюки иногда добавляют "звездочек"»_ - тут ключевое слово "иногда" :) Более беспроигрышный вариант зазвездиться на собеседовании, имхо, это ООП-решение через паттерны... сложно, зато ынтерпразно (сам не понимаю чем так важны JS-разработчику паттерны, но меня почти на каждом техн. собеседовании о них спрашивали ).

Comment: `console.log(...orderIds.map(id => people.find(item => item.id === id).name));` - а почему нельзя так? И почему вообще все выводят только имена объектов, когда вроде надо вывести объекты в порядке, указанном в `orderIds`?

Comment: @Leonid, так можно, но тогда поиск (вызов `find` проходящий по массиву) будет выполняться на каждой итерации `map` - это неэффективная лишняя возня с данными, плюс она добавляет вероятность ошибки. Поэтому каст массива в хэштабличку предпочтительнее: один раз пробежались, и далее используем моментальный доступ по ключу. _«И почему вообще все выводят только имена объектов, когда вроде надо вывести объекты в порядке, указанном в orderIds?»_ - потому что несмотря на формулировку ТСа, коммент в коде вoпроса показывает желаемый результат... лично я больше доверяю коду, чем словесному описанию)))

Comment: @Leonid, хотя приведенные здесь решения через хэштаблицу (мое, и Петра) тоже несовершенны: если в массиве окажутся объекты с одинаковым значением `id`, сохранится только последний объект (предыдущие дубли будут заменены на преобразовании, т.е. по факту потеряны). Подобный случай конечно из категории крайних, `id` дублируются редко (чаще они уникальны), но все же есть за данным подходом такой вот косячок. Обходится это через вложенную коллекцию (Array/Set/etc), если возникнет реальная потребность.

Comment: Помимо быстродействия есть еще и читаемость, я вот до сих пор разбираю ваш ответ, зная, что он выводит. Если бы я увидел этот код без возможности его запустить, то ни в жизнь бы не разобрал)))

Comment: Я заменил `Object.values(people).map()` на `people.map()` и ничего не изменилось.

Comment: @Leonid, ухудшение читаемости - плата за изоляцию хэштаблицы и скорое освобождение занимаемой ею памяти. Когда надо только побыстрее пометить объект на удаление (без его изоляции пределами выражения), вместо использования IIFE можно просто присвоить объектное значение `let`-переменной, и после работы с ним заменить значение (например на `null` или `undefined`), либо поместить `let`-объявление с кодом в "висячий" блок кода `{}`... но в JS такая забота о памяти это редкая практика. Впрочем, и IIFE тоже не особо часто применяется. За замечание о `Object.values` спасибо! Это и правда лишнее было.

Comment: @Leonid, для иллюстрации написанного о висячем блоке кода - [вот пример с ним](https://jsbin.com/fisuricuyo/edit?js,console). Может ты знаешь о таком трюке, это я просто на всякий случай -  ведь подобному обычно не учат вроде... это естественное следствие из "механики" объявлений через `let` и `const`: о нем типа "догадаться надо", и я вот далеко не сразу после выхода ES6 догадался (может просто я тормоз, хз  ).

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1098152/342397 - это мне кое-что напомнило)))) А я понял почему для меня не читаем код со спрэд-операторами литерала объектов, я вообще избегаю работать с объектами и, как результат, не знаю как с ними работать. И методов Object[method] я совершенно не знаю. Поэтому это не показатель. И стрелочная функция в теле IIFE для меня была в диковинку тоже. Спасибо, ради этого и стоит давать ответы, чтобы люди могли посмотреть на опыт других разработчиков. Это показательно, интересно и полезно.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129012/discussion-between-yar85-and-leonid).

Comment: Потратил минут 5-10, чтобы понять код, после уже кажется не таким уж и сложным) Однозначно плюсик.

Answer (score 2):

Коллега, подобный мелкий саботаж учебных заданий дорого обойдется при трудоустройстве. Сокращенный синтаксис управления объектами как множеством полей недвусмысленно сокращает время написания кода, его нужно знать!

```
const orderIds = [4, 2, 1, 3]

const people = [
    { id: 3, name: 'Tom'},
    { id: 2, name: 'Bill'},
    { id: 1, name: 'Jack'},
    { id: 4, name: 'Bob'}
]

const peopleMap = people.reduce((acm, cur) => ({...acm, [cur.id]: cur.name}), {});
console.log(...orderIds.map((id) => peopleMap[id]));
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Но не очень понял на счёт саботажа. 
Мне задали такую задачу на собеседовании, я не справился. Попросил помощи здесь. 
В чём саботаж? Не думаю, что кому-то создаст проблем этот вопрос, если он наткнётся на него перед своим собеседованием. Это должно быть просто мировое совпадение, если именно тому человеку попадётся этот вопрос именно на его следующем собеседовании)

Comment: @Spawnet В таком случае, обознался) Вопрос выглядит как домашняя работа абстрактного студента абстрактного института

Comment: Может так это и выглядит) Но по факту, это долбанный провал и потеря очень хорошей вакансии, чтоб меня(
Никак не идёт углублённый ES6.

Answer (score 2):

```js
const orderIds = [4, 2, 1, 3]

const people = [
    { id: 3, name: 'Tom'},
    { id: 2, name: 'Bill'},
    { id: 1, name: 'Jack'},
    { id: 4, name: 'Bob'}
]

let result = orderIds.map(el => people.filter(item => item.id == el)[0].name)
console.log(...result)
```

Comment: Благодарю! Компактно и понятно (станет со временем, когда это всё уляжется в голове)

Comment: Тогда логичнее использовать `find()` вместо `filter()[0]`. Выглядит очевиднее.